# How to List Folders of External Storage Android

Tags: android

I am working on Expansion Files . For this I am creating a testing project which will first download(save file manually on externall storage of device). As mentioned on google docs that by default on downloading expansion file save in external storgae of device on path /Android/obb/packagename. Now i want that i can maually save my file on external storage.So for this this first i want to see the list of folders in External Storage. So how can this be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dirs = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath());

if(dirs.exists()) {
    File[] files = dirs.listFiles();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this By using the code.

```
File extStorageDir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    String fileList=extStorageDir.list();

    for(String fileName:fileList)
    sysout("FileName="+fileNAme);
```